# Routing with a non optional parameter (not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

The site I'm building needs to have a users username as part of the url like:

> mydomain/user1

I have set this up in global.asa as:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SubscriptionList","{Username}/","~/subscriptionlist.aspx");
```

However if there are links on the site to pages that arent routed, for example, mydomain/login.aspx these get routed to the 'SubscriptionList' page. I presume that this is because the required URL `'{Username}/'` can actually be nothing. How do I set routing up so that the above only gets triggered when the Username actually exists?

The alternative, which I'm sure isnt best practice, is to set up a route for each page on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with the order of your routes in your routing table.

From what I understand, you should make sure that this route is below others that have explicit routing set.

For instance, this should be below the route than handles the routing to Login.aspx as I think  that rules are evaluated from top to bottom.

Or do I not understand the question=